# Show custom link in related list in object page layout?

Tags: related-list, custom-link

I have 2 custom objects (A and B), B have a loopkup field of A, so how to add custom link of B in object A's layout in related list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a formula field instead of custom link in object B and add in Object A

Comment: GI Joe, can formula field be used to run JavaScript, actually my custom link in Object B open up a new window where it calls apex class with one of the field value as parameter, will formula field can do that ?

Comment: Yes it will! Suppose say you have a visualforce page and you want to call the page try like this HYPERLINK('/apex/yourvfpage?id='+{!account.id},'click me') try like this